# How to draw text with opacity in canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I need help drawing see through text for my weather app.
I need the temperature displayed in opacity for a nice look,

How can I do this in Canvas?

Please Help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? We can help if you've given it a go and run into issues, but it's up to you do to the research up front - check the docs on the HTML5 canvas api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to play around with it but something like:

```
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// code to draw picture as normal

ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;

// code to draw text
</script>
</body>
</html>
```